# Web service listen on Public and Private IP address

Tags: windows, ip, private

I'm trying to get some applications of ours to listen on the Public IP address of the server. Due to the complex nature of these systems we cannot change the behavior of the applications or what IP address they are listening on.

Is there a way we can create some kind of basic web service on the public IP that simply forwards all requests through to the private listeners?

Our servers are Windows Server 2008 Enterprise.

Comment: Google "port forwarding".

Comment: Do you mean port forwarding on the server itself?? A google search is full of people asking how to set up their uTorrent and Minecraft servers. I'm essentially trying to do this on the box itself and not on the router or switch, any thoughts of where I can find this info?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can't change the app to listen on a public ip I would try using the firewall as your "proxy" by using NAT and port forwarding. You should be able to translate and forward traffic destined for a specific public ip/port to the private ip/port of the web server.

Comment: By 'the firewall' do you mean the windows firewall or are you suggesting making the changes in the physical firewall?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using IIS, you could use the URL Rewrite module to act as a reverse proxy.

Connections coming in to the site bound to the public IP address can be forwarded to the private IP address.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Our applications are not ISS however, I could very easily use IIS to do the forwarding to the other NIC if required. This looks like it might work. I'll give it a try and see how it goes